# How to use ui-router $stateProvider with html5 links

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to get ui-router stateProvider dynamic links to work on a site which uses html5 links.

This code works: [Plunker1](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4seR0pwXjO7PyDMoTh0)

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1");

  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        templateUrl: "route1.html"
    })
    .state('route1.list', {
        url: "/list/:id",
        templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
          $scope.items = ["Item One", "Item Two", "Item Three", "Item Four"];

          $scope.id = $stateParams.id; 
        }
    })

})
```

This code doesn't: [Plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5PwAuk37fDH3vhgnJa0)

When I add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); it stops working, and actually seems to send the browser into some kind of endless loop and I am not sure why.

When I add this state configuration to my code base I get an error that it is trying to load angular more than once. And I get a nested view of my site but nothing loading in route.list

```
...
<base href="/">
...
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
...
```

Comment: It does not work in Plunker because the base / would e run.plunkr.co .. which is wrong, and your template will not be found, have you tried it without plunker?

Comment: I've written a blog post about it ;) maybe this helps a bit: https://lingohub.com/blogs/2014/10/angularjs-migration-guide-1-2-to-1-3/

Comment: I have tried it without plunker. I don't get the same endless loop, but a nested view of the entire page and an error for reloading angular twice. The index has a `<div ui-view>` and so do the first level templates

Comment: I made a new plunk without `<base href="/">` and instead configured the location provider like you suggested in your blog post, but I am getting the same errors `$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });` Here's the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mvAwMfx9kEg7ubpVrXAU)

Comment: I think it cannot work in plunkr, you need to find the bug in your code! maybe a template (.html) is not found?